# Trying to get a sql query working in PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell

I am working on trying to pull information from a DB and compare against A.D. users, but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

I am pulling all the users in A.D. where EmployeeID is not null (just the EmployeeID itself), and then converting to a string:

```
$aUsers = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=*)" -Properties EmployeeID).EmployeeID
$b = ($aUsers -join ",")
```

I am then attempting to query the table for any users in the db that do NOT have a corresponding EmployeeID in A.D.:

```
"Select * from PS_WR_EE_CWR_CACHE Where EMPLID NOT IN (" + $b + ")"
```

But this gives me the error "Incorrect syntax near ','. If I do something manually, however, like so:

```
Select * from PS_WR_EE_CWR_CACHE Where EMPLID NOT IN (110, 111, 118)
```

it works perfectly. Not sure what in the syntax I am getting wrong that it won't take the list.

Comment: `"Select * from PS_WR_EE_CWR_CACHE Where EMPLID NOT IN ('{0}')" -f ($aUsers -join "','")`

Comment: I think what @SantiagoSquarzon is suggesting is that your EMPLID in the database is probably of CHAR type and not INT so you would need to place single quotes around each of the values.  i.e. `('110', '111', '118')`

Comment: So, by the way, if you were trying to find all users that don't have an `employeeID` why not ask AD directly, even tho slower than SQL it will save you one step. `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)"`

Comment: Thank you both, that helped. To your question, @SantiagoSquarzon, there are ~6000 users in the db that are NOT in A.D., that is what I am trying to return. So I do a pull from A.D., exactly as you have it, pulling only the EmployeeID, then run the query to pull any users in the DB NOT in that EmployeeID list.

Comment: Good point, well glad it worked :) @JLogan3o13